# Using the Map function in order to assign letters to ASCll code and then using the encrpytions output the word the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>



using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    map<string, string> codes = {{"a", "&#97"},{"b", "&#98;"},{"c", "&#99;"},{"d", "&#100;"},{"e","&#101;"},{"f", "&#102;"},{"g", "&#103;"},
                                {"h", "&#104;"}, {"i", "&#105;"},{"j", "&#106;"},{"k","&#107;"},{"l","&#108;"},{"m","&#109;"},{"n","&#110;"},
                                {"o", "&#111;"},{"p","&#112;"},{"q","&#113;"},{"r","&#114;"},{"s","&#115;"},{"t","&#116;"},{"u","&#117;"},
                                {"v","&#118;"},{"w","&#119;"},{"x", "&#120;"},{"y","&#121;"},{"z","&#122;"} };

    cout << "Welcome user, the challenge today has you encrypting this sentence in ASCII format:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout  << "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" << endl; 
    cout << endl;
    string encrypt;

    while (encrypt != "Quit") {
        cin >> encrypt;
        
        cout << codes[encrypt] << endl;
    }
    

    return 0; 
}
```

So right now, I'm having an Issue understanding how I can reverse the input so instead of when I type &#97 and it displays a, it will display the ASCll code. I'm also having trouble trying how to basically set it to where once you have inputted all the ASCll codes and when you stop the program so it'll print out the response.

Comment: You do realize that your `map` is completely redundant, don't you? You don't need a `map` to convert letters into entities and vice versa.

Comment: It's not the point it's a project I'm working on and it involves me using a map.

Comment: A `map` only runs one way efficiently. Input key, get value. If you wanted to get the key for a particular value, you'd have to linearly iterate the `map` looking for the correct value and then return the key. This is as stupid as it sounds. The path of least resistance to inputting "&#97" and getting back "a" is to have a second `map` with the reverse relationship. "&#97" becomes the key and "a" becomes the value.

Comment: "*The path of least resistance to inputting "&#97" and getting back "a" is to have a second map with the reverse relationship*" - no , the path of least resistance is to simply not use a map at all. Just extract `"97"`, convert it to an integer, and then type-cast it.

Comment: Can't argue that. Allow me to reword to insert a "If you have to use a `map`,"

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown doesn't work, because you are passing the entire input `std::string` as-is to `map::operator[]`, when you need to instead pass the individual characters of the `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    map<char, string> codes = { {'a', "&#97"},   {'b', "&#98;"},  {'c', "&#99;"},  {'d', "&#100;"}, {'e', "&#101;"}, {'f', "&#102;"}, {'g', "&#103;"},
                                {'h', "&#104;"}, {'i', "&#105;"}, {'j', "&#106;"}, {'k', "&#107;"}, {'l', "&#108;"}, {'m', "&#109;"}, {'n', "&#110;"},
                                {'o', "&#111;"}, {'p', "&#112;"}, {'q', "&#113;"}, {'r', "&#114;"}, {'s', "&#115;"}, {'t', "&#116;"}, {'u', "&#117;"},
                                {'v', "&#118;"}, {'w', "&#119;"}, {'x', "&#120;"}, {'y', "&#121;"}, {'z', "&#122;"} };

    cout << "Welcome user, the challenge today has you encrypting this sentence in ASCII format:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout  << "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    string input;
    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        for (char ch : input) {
            cout << codes[ch] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

To reverse the process, you will have to scan through the "encrypted" string looking for `&#<number>;` sequences, and then for each sequence you can scan through the `std::map` to find a matching value, and if found then you will know the letter from its key, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    map<char, string> codes = { {'a', "&#97"},   {'b', "&#98;"},  {'c', "&#99;"},  {'d', "&#100;"}, {'e', "&#101;"}, {'f', "&#102;"}, {'g', "&#103;"},
                                {'h', "&#104;"}, {'i', "&#105;"}, {'j', "&#106;"}, {'k', "&#107;"}, {'l', "&#108;"}, {'m', "&#109;"}, {'n', "&#110;"},
                                {'o', "&#111;"}, {'p', "&#112;"}, {'q', "&#113;"}, {'r', "&#114;"}, {'s', "&#115;"}, {'t', "&#116;"}, {'u', "&#117;"},
                                {'v', "&#118;"}, {'w', "&#119;"}, {'x', "&#120;"}, {'y', "&#121;"}, {'z', "&#122;"} };

    cout << "Welcome user, the challenge today has you encrypting this sentence in ASCII format:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout  << "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    string input;

    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        for (char ch : input) {
            cout << codes[ch] << endl;
        }
    }

    cout  << "now, enter the codes back in" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        for (auto &entry : codes) {
            if (entry.second == input) {
                cout << entry.first << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

However, as you can see, `std::map` is not well-suited for this kind of reverse lookup.  You could setup a separate `std::map` for the code-to-letter lookup, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    map<char, string> codes = { {'a', "&#97"},   {'b', "&#98;"},  {'c', "&#99;"},  {'d', "&#100;"}, {'e', "&#101;"}, {'f', "&#102;"}, {'g', "&#103;"},
                                {'h', "&#104;"}, {'i', "&#105;"}, {'j', "&#106;"}, {'k', "&#107;"}, {'l', "&#108;"}, {'m', "&#109;"}, {'n', "&#110;"},
                                {'o', "&#111;"}, {'p', "&#112;"}, {'q', "&#113;"}, {'r', "&#114;"}, {'s', "&#115;"}, {'t', "&#116;"}, {'u', "&#117;"},
                                {'v', "&#118;"}, {'w', "&#119;"}, {'x', "&#120;"}, {'y', "&#121;"}, {'z', "&#122;"} };

    map<char, string> letters = { {"&#97", 'a'},   {"&#98;", 'b'},  {"&#99;", 'c'},  {"&#100;", 'd'}, {"&#101;", 'e'}, {"&#102;", 'f'}, {"&#103;", 'g'},
                                  {"&#104;", 'h'}, {"&#105;", 'i'}, {"&#106;", 'j'}, {"&#107;", 'k'}, {"&#108;", 'l'}, {"&#109;", 'm'}, {"&#110;", 'n'},
                                  {"&#111;", 'o'}, {"&#112;", 'p'}, {"&#113;", 'q'}, {"&#114;", 'r'}, {"&#115;", 's'}, {"&#116;", 't'}, {"&#117;", 'u'},
                                  {"&#118;", 'v'}, {"&#119;", 'w'}, {"&#120;", 'x'}, {"&#121;", 'y'}, {"&#122;", 'z'} };

    cout << "Welcome user, the challenge today has you encrypting this sentence in ASCII format:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout  << "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    string input;
    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        for (char ch : input) {
            cout << codes[ch] << endl;
        }
    }

    cout  << "now, enter the codes back in" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        cout << letters[input] << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

However, you don't actually need the `map`s at all.  Simply type-cast a `char` into an integer to get its numeric code. And parse an entity code to extract its integer and then cast that back to a `char`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    cout << "Welcome user, the challenge today has you encrypting this sentence in ASCII format:" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout  << "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    string input;

    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        for (char ch : input) {
            cout << "&#" << static_cast<int>(ch) << ";" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout  << "now, enter the codes back in" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    while (cin >> input && input != "Quit") {
        string s = input.substr(2, input.size()-3);
        int i = stoi(s);
        cout << static_cast<char>(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: May I ask for future refrence how to include spaces in between writing "the quick fox jumped over the lazy dog"?

Comment: `operator>>` ignores spaces, so if you need to preserve spaces, use `std::getline()` instead.